# Setting an environment variable when running default Debug command in Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubymine

I have feature specs in my Rails app that use Capybara to run tests through a browser. By default they use the phantomjs/poltergeist and rack-test drivers, which are headless.

It often is desirable to run a single spec (or spec file) using a capybara driver that runs a visible browser so that I can see what is happening. For this use case I use Selenium. When I want to run a spec using Selenium I set an environment variable (DEBUG=true) before running rspec like so:

```
DEBUG=true rspec spec/features/my_spec.rb
```

My spec_helper looks for the DEBUG environment variable and runs the spec with Selenium instead of the default drivers. I'd like to duplicate this capability in Rubymine, so that when I right-click on a spec in the project tree and click "Debug 'Run spec...'" it sets up the DEBUG environment variable and runs the spec with the Selenium driver. How can I configure the default 'Debug' configuration to set up this environment variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Next to the run button on the tool bar, there's the name of the configuration that is active, click it and choose `Edit Configuration` inside you'll find `server arguments` you can write there the `DEBUG=true` and it will be sent to the runner file.

[image: Location of configuration]